# master detail grid with backbone.js and jquery

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

as a part of my project, i have to build a master detail grid component using backbone.js and jquery which can be used in any other application i.e. it should be a reusable component. when a developer for a particular application uses this component in his application, he should be able to populate the grid with relevant data and other similar functionalities. could anyone please help me with that? i'm unfamiliar with both backbone.js and jquery and although i have been trying to learn these two, i have been unable to make any significant progress. and also i can't do this using any other framework or language.so please help

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend downloading and digging into [Backgrid.js](http://backgridjs.com/), which to my knowledge is the only grid built specifically to run on Backbone's Collections out of the box.  Notice how each row represents a model, which will update or add/remove as data changes, thanks to use of Backbone's events (change, add, etc) in the Backgrid code. It's the most concise and proper use of Backbone's data to build a grid out there, bar none.

As for master/detail, to my knowledge nobody has done it for Backgrid yet.  However, [Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) has it included, and that's certainly a place to look for inspiration.  I personally wouldn't recommend trying to bolt Datatables onto Backbone.....I've tried, twice.  Event handling gets quite iffy because Datatables has its own data model, and you end up brute forcing re-draws to keep the data in sync.

Hopefully that will get you going.  Stack Overflow is a great place to ask questions once you have an attempt in progress.

Comment: yes i actually have understood and infact built a grid using backbone, but it's the linking of the master and detail grid that's causing me problems. thanks for the help, i'll look into it\

Comment: If you dig into datatables, you'll see that they do it as an additional column on the table.  Then, they use Javascript to show/hide it as a div in the displayed table.